# zsh tab-completion for filenames works for some commands, but not others

Tags: macos, zsh

I wrote a little shell script that lives in the current directory and I invoke it like this: `./import <command> <file>`. When I try using tab to complete the filename, `zsh` just beeps at me.

However, I can complete the same file using a command like `ls` or `zip`. In the examples below, I hit tab after typing `../S`:

```bash
% ./import capitalone ../S<BEEP>
% ls ../Source\ Docs/    (no issue)
% zip ../Source\ Docs/    (no issue)
```

I’ve tried googling for an answer to this, but all I find is other kinds of tab-completion issues. I also tried reading through the zsh completion manual but found that to be really complex, and it wasn’t immediately obvious what the answer might be.

*Update:* Added some requested debugging output:

```bash
% ./import asdf ./
tags in context :completion::complete:import::
    options   (_arguments _x_arguments _imagemagick) 
    messages  (_message _arguments _x_arguments _imagemagick)
tags in context :completion::complete:import:options:
    options  (_arguments _x_arguments _imagemagick)
```

Comment: Please press `CTRL+x` then `h` instead of `TAB`. You should get a debugging output, please add this output here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *zsh* completion system is very powerful as it not only completes file names but also arguments to commands. Try for example `ls -<TAB>`.

However, in your case, *zsh* is trying to complete arguments to the `import` command, which obviously belongs to the *image magick* package, as can be seen in the debug output:

```
tags in context :completion::complete:import:options:
```

I see three possibilities:

1. Rename your command to something which does not trigger special completions, like `my_import`.
2. Disable the completion for `import` with this command:

   ```
   compdef -d import
   ```

   Be aware that you need to put this into your *zsh* configuration (most likely `~/.zshrc`) to make it permanent.
3. Write you own completion function, specific for your `import` command... `;)`

Comment: So, zsh just does a simple name match for argument completion. I guess. Would be cool if I could specify completion info in a script header comment, rather than separate from my script. Thanks!

Comment: @Rick: I don't think this is possible, but I'm definitively no completion system wizard.